# Customize org-mode priorities

Tags: org-mode

I want to replace the default org-mode priorities with my own.

default: `#A #B #C`
desired: `#1 #2 #3 #4 #5`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 10):

You can customize priorities in the group `org-priorities`. `M-x customize-group`, then type `org-priorities`.

Accepted values are A to Z and 0 to 9, so you can actually set your desired priorities.

Be sure to customize the 3 settings:

- `org-highest-priority`
- `org-lowest-priority`
- `org-default-priority`

Comment: If I would like to configure this in .emacs what do I need to write?

Comment: I found out, it works with `(setq org-highest-priority ?G)`.

Answer (score 7):

An easier manner: 
at the beginning of your org file, set the following:

```
#+PRIORITIES: 1 5 3
```

You can read more about it [here](http://orgmode.org/manual/Priorities.html).

Comment: Welcome to emacs.SE! This is nice to set different priorities for a specific buffer.  I would also suggest you include a link to the relevant doc (http://orgmode.org/manual/Priorities.html)

Comment: One point to bear in mind with custom priorities is that you need "equal" spacing between the low, mid, and high.  For example if `#+PRIORITIES 1 10 5` will not work because `5-1 = 4` and `10 - 5 = 5`.  You would need `#+PRIORITIES 1 9 5`.

Comment: It's true that it won't work with 10, but the actual reason is that only single characters are allowed as priorities. "Equal spacing" is not necessary.