# Customize Org Priorities with Strings

Tags: org-mode

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12791/customize-org-mode-priorities) about changing labels on priorities. The question refers to setting the org-mode priorities to something like `#1 #2 #3 #4 #5` instead of `#A #B #C`. Now, from the org-mode documentation it appears that `org-highest-priority`, `org-lowest-priority`, and `org-default-priority` must be in alphabetical order. In addition, these priorities are chars, and thus cannot be replaced with a string. I take it this is because org-mode computes display order of priorities in the agenda using direct comparison operators on the priorities. Now, the question becomes, is there an easy way to *display* the priorities as something like `High`, `Medium`, and `Low`, even if underneath it treats it as `#A #B #C`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Background**:  Emacs converts the priority letters or numbers into character numbers for purposes of sorting, etc. -- e.g., `(string-to-char "A")` is 65.

Option #1:  Use a tag.

```
* Active [#A] Hello-world. :TOP:@home:
  DEADLINE: <2017-01-10 Tue>
```

Option #2:  Use a heading priority separator and sort (at least in part) by priorities:

```
* Active [#A] .;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; TOP ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;. :TOP:@home:
DEADLINE: <2017-01-10 Tue>

* Active [#A] Hello-world. :@home:
  DEADLINE: <2017-01-10 Tue>
```

Option #3:  Use a properties drawer.

Option #4:  Play with overlays and display them in the location desired -- some assembly required.

Option #5:  Do not look for the easy way out and invest the time to modify the behavior of `org-mode` to support priorities such as those indicated in the question hereinabove.  To begin on this quest, have a look at the variable `org-get-priority-function` and the function `org-get-priority`.

Comment: To whomever placed a downvote, or whoever wants to place another downvote, please familiarize yourself with the `org-mode` source code before downvoting.  Start by looking at the variable and function mentioned in option number 5 to begin with.

Comment: Surely they misread the labels and intended to renice your comprehensive answer